# Jquery loading locally, but not on the web server

Tags: jquery

Running the files locally everything works perfectly.

I've tried uploading the site files to both Godaddy and Github, but the Jquery doesn't load in either case. In both cases HTML and CSS work as expected.

I have an alert ('script.js is loaded'); at the top of my Jquery. The alert appears when running locally, but not via Godaddy or Github.

I have at the top of my HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='Jquery.js'></script>
```

After Googling, I've tried using TextEdit (instead of Sublime) files instead, but to no avail. I'm struggling to find any other ideas.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: try to point src with out protocol, like this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: To be clear, you are not saying jquery is not loading, but your file named Jquery.js?  Can you access Jquery.js on the remote server directly? is it in the same folder as this file? Do you have a base tag set?

Comment: Check if there is any error in console on server site??